# If $f$ is a $0$-form and $dx$ a $1$-form, then does $f\ dx=f\wedge dx$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

If $f$ is a $0$-form and $dx$ a $1$-form, then does $f\ dx=f\wedge dx$?

Background: I am trying to prove that $d(f\ dx)=df\wedge dx$ using only the four properties of $d$:

(1) $d(w+v)=dw+dv$

(2) $d(w\wedge v)=dw\wedge v+(-1)^{\deg w}w\wedge dv$

(3) $f$ is a $0$-form $\implies df$ is the differential of $f$

(4) $f$ is a $0$-form $\implies d^2f=0$

My proof: $d(f\ dx)=d(f\wedge dx)=df\wedge dx+f\wedge d^2x=df\wedge dx$. The second and third equal signs come from property 2 and 4 respectively. But the first one must come from $f\ dx=f\wedge dx$. My question is why this is true.

Although it seems very trivial, I believe a rigorous explanation is as follows: Let $A$ be the alternating map from the tensor product of $0$-forms and $1$-forms to its subspace of alternating tensors. **Then by definition $f\wedge dx=A(f\otimes dx)$**. But there is a multiplication defined between $0$-forms and $1$-forms, so that tensoring means multiplying, and $f\otimes dx= f\ dx$. And $A$, as the alternating map over $1$-forms, is actually the identity. Hence $f\wedge dx=A(f\otimes dx)=f\ dx$

Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: what is your definition of $f dx$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Just the usual multiplication.

Comment: how do you multiply an apple and a mango? How do you multiply a $0$-form and a $1$-form? Then, what is the role of $f\wedge dx$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik There is a multiplication defined between them. Don't forget that a $0$-form is also a real-valued function. Fixing a base point for this function you get a real number. A $1$-form is a smooth section of the exterior $1$-form bundle. Fixing a base point for a $1$-form, you get a cotangent vector. Now you can multiply the real number with the cotangent vector. Do this for every base point you define the multiplication between a $0$-form and a $1$-form.

Comment: I have nothing to say. Hope some one helps you... Have you seen your above explanation in any book or did you come up with this idea on your own?

Comment: Usually by definition of the wedge product, $f\wedge \omega=f\omega$ for any differential form $\omega$. You'll have to give us your definition of the wedge product if you don't think this is part of its definition.

Comment: @jgon I actually did. Check the words in bold.

Comment: @Travis Sorry about that. Should've been a wedge product.

Comment: oof how come now on answered it yet